# How to Integrate Payment Gateway Feature in Android

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

How to **Integrate Payment Gateway Feature** in *Android App*, I have made a *Shopping Cart App* in which now i want to add Payment Gateway Feature, please suggest me... the *best way to allow user to do Payments*

Should i need to use some *readymade classes* or need to *import any Payment SDK*....

Comment: what's wrong with this question, why it has been downvoted?

Comment: @Raynold link is not working

Comment: Looks like it was removed, try these http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/test_user_setup.html

http://www.webassist.com/support/documentation/how-tos/paypal_sandbox.php

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox#accounts

Comment: You are directly asking for code or suggestion, which is **wrong**, instead you should google it first and ask a question with some code & error to solve it, that would be a real question. P.S. however, i havent downvoted your question yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi @JimmyHill few days ago i was in same situation and this link helped me :
http://knowledge.itdoctorz.com/141/

Use below code:

```
Public void onClick (View v) {

PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(“8.25″));

payment.setCurrencyType(“USD”);

payment.setRecipient(“.....@gmail.com”);

payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);

Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, this);

startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);

}
```

I hope this link will help you :)

Update::

Added the new link to the answer which have a detailed steps to integrate payment gateway feature in android

Link :: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

Comment: http://knowledge.itdoctorz.com/141/ the link is dead